# Prompts for windows authentication when viewing a page in Web site

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-authentication, html

When i try to view a PARTICULAR page in my web site, it prompts for user name and password. Irrespective of providing proper user name/password and clicking OK or directly clicking Cancel button, the page is getting loaded properly. I am not sure why the authentication screen appears!!! It happens only for that particular page. Initially I thought it could be with file permission but copy pasted another page (which works fine) and renaming it doesn't solve the problem. Thoughts pl.

**EDIT**

I copied the source from the browser for that particular page and saved it as HTML. When i try to open the HTML file, it prompts for authentication.

**Solution**

I disabled the Integrated Windows Authentication in IIS and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabled the Integrated Windows Authentication in IIS and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

It's because some content is linked to a page that requires that (i.e. an image or a css file or a JavaScript file). Find out what it is, and make sure the link is correct.

Comment: But that doesn't happen when i run my application from VS. It happens only when i deploy the application in server

Comment: @Sri: Nevertheless, it's still the problem. (At least it's my guess of the problem).

Comment: @Sri - Your VS is probably running in Admin mode (prompt when you open VS is Vista/7/Server 2008), so you are not getting the prompt there.  Check your NTFS permissions on all resources tied to that web page and/or comment out resources that @silky mentioned until you find the one causing the issues.

Comment: I disabled the Integrated Windows Authentication in IIS and it works fine.